# Regular Points for interpolation

Tags: qgis, point, interpolation, vector-grid, regular-expression

I want to create a windmap. So I created a csv with coordinates with values for wind speed and direction, these represent my weather stations. I loaded the csv up in QGIS and marked a station. Then I chose Raster ==> interpolation ==> I chose the value direction and clicked "add". Then I chose the interpolation method Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) for processing. Now I have a raster for my speed value and I have also processed one for the direction value.

Here is my Question:

Now I want to put a regular points grid over my interpolated rasters but it doesn't shows up? So I go to Vector ==> research tools ==> regular points.

Every time I want to create a regular points grid it proceeds and gives a result wich is an empty "regular points" layer?

I tried to use a layer, as a mask, and also tried it without a mask layer.

There are no errors or obvious failures? I tried it with other rasters and there were no problems at all.

It would be great to get some ideas and help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the simple solution.... the failure was the distance (point spacing)... i choosed a scale wich was to wide. So just keep a small distance between the points of your grid and it it will work.